# Trigger to make autonumber field on account with format 'ACC-001'

Tags: trigger, auto-number

I need to create a trigger that will autopopulate the field created in Account object.
The field value will be auto populated using the value like 'ACC-001','ACC-002' everytime an account is created.
Can you guys help with the logic??

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using standard auto number field ?

Comment: Get the count of all records and based on it populate auto number field.

Comment: @VijayGanji, hi Vijay..... its not for project implementation purpose. Its for self learning, if is there any other way through triggers, we can implement it using autonumber

Comment: @MIXDML ; yes, i can do that. i will count the records and will append it to 'ACC' . i mean, its field is a text field that will be worked upon as autonumber.

Comment: i need a format 'ACC' + '001'. i am getting Acc1,Acc2.... Acc11 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, there are better approaches on the platform to do this. You want to get the count of records, and then convert the count to a string. Lastly, it looks like you want to pad with 0's. I think this ought to do the trick:

```
Integer count = [SELECT count() FROM Account];
Integer maxDigits = 10;
String countStr  = String.valueOf(count);
String str = 'ACC' + countStr.leftPad(maxDigits - countStr.length(), '0');
```

This code should be fine even if you have 'more than 50,0000' Accounts. In the Summer '18 release they changed how the `count()` works in SOQL

> Previously, each individual record matched by the SOQL COUNT() and COUNT(fieldName) functions counted toward the query row limit. So requesting a count could have a significant impact on governor limits, especially when working with many records. Now, if a query using one of these functions returns an integer, it only counts as one query row toward the governor limit.

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_apex_soql_count_limits.htm